# SSL integration with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl

I would like to know how the SSL is processing internally by iOS. I have seen in some post that certificate has to bundle with the resources, but in some post which is not mentioned.

1) Is it necessary to add .cer file along with the app resources?

2) Also, I have read Authentication Challenge delegate method has to be implemented and in this case, how iOS is working internally.

```
URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:delegate
```

3) For securing TCP Socket communication, I have read that  NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey has to be set to NSStream object. I am curious to know how iOS internally handles the security with SSL in this case also.

Comment: You probably need to start telling us whether you're contemplating client authentication or just the more usual server authentication, whether the certificates are signed by well-known CAs or not...

Comment: I want to protect the app from all kind of threats and I'm not sure abt the ways of hacking. So, considering the security, I have seen SSL will help for protection during gateway communication via web services. Also, I am using TCP socket communication with the gateway using NSStream. I have seen by setting NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey  for NSStream object, iOS will protect. I would like to knw by setting NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey and implementing Authenticating Challenge delegate methods, how iOS is providing security.

Comment: How the SSL works if the certificates are signed by well-known CAs or not and what are the differences in both the cases.

Comment: Your question is probably a bit too broad to get meaningful answers, you should read more about SSL/TLS. If you are doing only server authentication, and the server certificate is signed by a well-known CA, then you don't need to bundle any certificate in your app. You would only need one if you wanted to do client authentication (that would be the client cert) or if the server certificate is not signed (directly or indirectly) by one of the CAs known to iOS (you would then include the signing CA cert).

Comment: As to how "iOS is doing things internally", you should not be concerned with that. The only thing you can rely on is what the documentation says. Anything else can change at any time. However, if you're interested in how they currently do things, a lot of the security-related code is actually public, you can just read it.